# listener + jquery object + trigger change event + append

Tags: jquery, append, listener

listener + jquery object + trigger change ebent + append

I want to :

1. set up listener
2. define HTML option box
3. convert html to jquery object
4. trigger a change event - to fire the listner
5. append results to existing DOM element

Of this step #4 is not working

```
// add listener on  change in options
$('.cl_preAction').on("change",function(){                  
    alert("");
})'

// set up html string with options
    glCfgSection =  <select name='ACTC' class='cl_preAction' id='cl_preAction' data-theme='a'>\n\
        <option data-location='T' value='001'>Option 1</option>\n\
        <option data-location='T' value='002'>Option 2</option>\n\
        <option data-location='T' value='003'>Option 3</option>\n\
        <option data-location='T' value='004'>Option 4</option>\n\
    </select>\n\";

    // convert string to jquery object
    myTmpl = $(glCfgSection);   

     // trigger a change event - neither of these seem to work
     //$('.cl_preAction option', myTmpl).change();               
     $('.cl_preAction option', myTmpl).trigger('change');        

     // append to page (jQuery Mobile)
     myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+glCurrentTab).trigger('create');   // this works
```

Comment: If you need to call that directly, why not make extra function and call that function from change event and straight when you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 changes you will have to make.

1. Since you are creating dynamic elements you need to use event delegation based handlers
2. Since event delegation is used the handlers are registered to an ancestor element, so the event triggering will call the handlers only if the element is added to the dom structure

Try

```
// use event delegation to handle dynamic elements
$(document).on("change",'.cl_preAction', function(){                  
    alert("");
});

// set up html string with options
glCfgSection =  "<select name='ACTC' class='cl_preAction' id='preAction' data-theme='a'>\n\
<option data-location='T' value='001'>Option 1</option>\n\
<option data-location='T' value='002'>Option 2</option>\n\
<option data-location='T' value='003'>Option 3</option>\n\
<option data-location='T' value='004'>Option 4</option>\n\
</select>\n"; 

// convert string to jquery object 
myTmpl = $(glCfgSection);    

// append to page (jQuery Mobile) 
//fire the event after adding the element to dom because the listener is added to the document object 
myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+glCurrentTab).trigger('change').trigger('create');   // this works (edited string delimiters)
```

Comment: brilliant! I could have spent the whole day looking at this!